# Uncaught TypeError: jQuery complete()

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have read like 4 or 5 questions here and i cant find a solution, i have this function

```
function combo_Produto()
{
 ....
   var Link = $('#LINK').val() + '/?action=_ajax_inventory&CodInventario='+CodInventario;
    var config = {
        url: Link,
        ComboboxID: ComboID,
        AutoSelect: true,
        allowClear: false,
        Advanced: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        placeholder: 'Produto',
        data: {
            LoadAllProducts: '1',
            EstadoProduto: EstadoProduto
        }
    }
   return combobox_ajax(config);
}
```

that i call later by

```
combo_Produto().complete(function(){
......});
```

But im getting: Uncaught TypeError: combo_Produto(...).completeis not a function. I have a return in my function so why wont he let me do the complete?

EDIT:
I have tried the `.done()` too.

Comment: Whatever `combobox_ajax` returns doesn't have a `complete` function.

Comment: it does have a return

Comment: I'm sure it does, but whatever it returns doesn't have a `complete` function inside of it.

Comment: jquery has function to handle promise https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/. Depends on the return type of your combobox_ajax(config).  You might want to do something like `$.when(combobox_ajax(config)).then()`. Just check the official doc by yourself

Comment: i already tried the ````when```` with ````done()```` and ````complete()```` if i use it with ````done()```` it stops the error but wont work either, and with ````complete```` it gives me another error and wont work to.

Comment: @AlexisGarcia without knowing the content of combobox_ajax() and it's return type, and what's the problem you are facing (certain variable you want to access after ajax complete) , there is literally not way to understand your question. That why ppl suggest try. You have to include the function in your problem.

Answer (score -1):

you can give a try.I think it can help you.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.when(function1()).then(function(){
    function2();
   });
})


function function1(){
   console.log('this is first');
}
function function2(){
    console.log('this is second');
 }
```